# check if the admin is inside the specific page on the back end

Tags: wp-admin

how to check if the the admin is inside the specific page inside the admin dashboard to show him specific result or a search query where developer wanna implement the result on that particular page not every where the code will be in function file

Comment: You can use [`get_current_screen()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/) to see what screen you're on in the backend.